# Properly setting the SKCameraNode's size/scale in a large SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I'm wanting to create a simple game where you fly around a large game scene in SpriteKit, with a camera following the player. It will be a portrait-oriented game.

What I'm wondering is how to *properly* set up the dimensions of the SKScene and SKCameraNode. I understand that the SKCameraNode's "size" (viewport size?) will match SKScene.size (assuming the scale=1.0).

So am I expected to just make an arbitrarily large scene, say for example square shaped, and then use some weird scaling numbers in the SKCameraNode to make its aspect ratio line up with that of the iPhone?

I ask this because I was following a tutorial that didn't really address this, and the result is that I had a SKScene that ended up being smaller than all of the objects inside of it (to make the camera's aspect ratio correct). Projectiles would just disappear because they'd have exited the bounds of the scene, however that part of the scene (and past it!) would still be in view! Obviously, I know this is wrong, but I want to know what the best way to fix it is.

Thanks very much!